# Unable to deploy react app to AWS amplify: deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort,

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

Im unable to deploy my app in AWS Amplify here is the error

```
                                # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm rebuild bootstrap && npm install
2023-04-22T23:00:20.516Z [INFO]: rebuilt dependencies successfully
2023-04-22T23:00:32.996Z [WARNING]: npm
G]: /codebuild/output/src510865731/src/web/src/scripts/tiltAnimation.js:1:25
                                    > 1 | import VanillaTilt from "vanilla-tilt";
                                    >   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    2 |
                                    3 | export default function initTiltAnimation() {
2023-04-22T23:00:47.260Z [INFO]: 
2023-04-22T23:00:47.443Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-04-22T23:00:47.443Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-04-22T23:00:47.444Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-04-22T23:00:47.444Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

here is my package json:

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "v16.19.0",
    "npm": "8.19.3"
  },
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Hadibadi99/web"
  },
  ...
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/cobiwave/simplefolio#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.8.3",
    "parcel": "^2.8.3",
    "prettier": "^2.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "vanilla-tilt": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

and here is my amplify.yml

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm rebuild bootstrap && npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

I tried to update parcel package and bootstrap and i also tried to add npm rebuild bootstrap before npm install in amplify.yml i also specified the node version in package.json

```
"engines": {
    "node": "v16.19.0",
    "npm": "8.19.3"
  }
```